Is the truth real and external or just a mental structure?
Does truth exist as an absolute concept, or is it merely a mental and relative construct shaped by culture, language, and human experience?

There's truth-predicate theory so that they can be absolutized in the sense of syntax, OTOH there's deflationary theory of truth or aleatoric nihilism where truth is redundant and the liar paradox could be easily resolved...

It may be that one's mental construct of truth is that truth is absolute. It might be an absolute truth that Earth orbits the sun, but in the raw state of nature there is nothing called 'Earth' so absolute truth has no object to connect to.
Heidegger suggests two forms of truth in On Time & Being (1964), page 69

Insofar as truth is understood in the traditional "natural" sense as
the correspondence of knowledge with beings demonstrated in beings, ...
also insofar as truth is interpreted as the certainty of the knowledge of Being, ...

The "correspondence of knowledge with beings (things)" is that a notion [that the Earth orbits the sun] may be found to correspond to the observation of Earth's orbit (things), and this is done by people so "demonstrated in beings (people)".
The "certainty of the knowledge of Being" is the direct certainty of one's existence, required for "demonstrating in beings".  So a novel take there.  The correspondence of existence with itself.

Doesn't the correspondence of existence then mean that there is a dependency and therefore the truth must be a mental construct? I am sorry, I read your answer 4 times and I am still not sure if you meant to say truth is absolute or a mental construct?

@Philomath lol, I see, "existence" as absolute you mean, perhaps. I mean 'existence' as in one's living experience.  So my observation may confirm the truth of "the moon is bright", so my experience/existence is truth-maker, and furthermore my experience/existence has its own truth in its certainty of itself. If one were to think it in terms of correspondence it would be a trivial case because it confirms its truth by evidencing itself.

So, you agree it's a mental construct? I feel so dumb...

@Philomath Well I'm speculating on Heidegger's 'suggestions'(?) "insofar" as he cautiously suggests these interpretations [mental constructs] of truth may be true. So I don't think that is saying conclusively that truth is such and such, (as the truth of truth). There is no real arbiter. 'Truth' is a word that means different things to different people. 'Absolute' suggests a platonic supersensory interpretation though.

But is a truth of correspondence (as cited above) a mental construct? The truth of "the moon is bright" is ascertained when I look and check. Anyone else can check that truth and it will be the same, so it is a fact of the world – an existentially shared world, noting that "The world of Dasein is a with-world (Mitwelt). So it seems, more than a mental construct. By the way, prior to 1964 Heidegger had a different notion of truth, as unconcealment.

Already Protagoras (c. 490 BC – c. 420 BC) noted

that "Of all things the measure is Man, of the things that are, that they are, and of the things that are not, that they are not" which was usually rendered simply as "Man is the measure of all things," interpreted (possibly wrongly, since he disagreed) by Plato to mean that there is no objective truth; Protagoras seems to have meant that each person's own personal history, experiences and expectations, developed over their lifetime, determine their judgments, opinions, and statements regarding "truth" (which is the title of the book in which Protagoras made this statement). When a person makes a judgment about a certain thing—good or bad or beautiful or unjust—that person will differ from other people's judgments because their experience has been different.

I think that truth, like other ideas, is not objective and universal, but human enterprise and interpretation. We built them over nature, where we can discern and distinguish evidence for them.
I illustrated and elaborated this point of view
in the recent note about my philosophy of mathematics, which is sometimes believed to be fundamental, universal and objective truth or knowledge. The note is brief but contains many references.

While Plato's true world is the supersensory world of ideal forms beyond the human world, we can still have objective true facts in the human world. Even if "man is the measure", still everyone measures a meter the same. Descartes' worldless cogito ergo sum overly separates human beings from each other, so Heidegger posits being-in-the-world as fundamental to man (Dasein) – a shared world ("The world of Dasein is a with-world [Mitwelt]") in which we can have objective truths: facts.
